# Accessing Data - view state vs calling store procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, design-patterns

In the asp.net user control i am using about 7-8 propoerties and saving small data (i.e. ID, Status etc) in view state.

I am wondering if it is better to access the required value by calling store procedure instead of saving them in view state.

I was using view states to reduce network traffic by not calling store procedure but don't know if it is right to do as having alot of view states can effect page performance.

Comment: In addition to AcidJunkie's answer, you may also want to consider the nature of your data. Can you lose your "small data" without any repurcussions? Does your application require this data? Do you need to get this data after someone has just opened your website? Your viewstate is lost when you close your browser or go to a different webpage.

Comment: I know how view state works and it is specific to one page. Data in view state will be used b/w during saving and binding record.

Answer (score 1):

There is not general "best way". it really depends on

- how much data will be stored in the view state in conjunction to the network bandwitdh
- how expensive is the database query

As an alternative to storing data in the viewstate, you could use some serverside caching inside your service layer

Comment: Data in viewstate is important and don't know if it is a good idea to save in cache? Can it lost?

Comment: Well, viewstate also can get lost. Do not expect us here to solve architectual decisions that you should do taking all aspects into consideration.